# How to install packages for racket?

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, installation, racket

I'm *Ubuntu* OS user. I'm trying install package for racket as following command

```
$ raco pkg install sicp
```

But When I ran this command in my system, I got an unexpected error as given below

```
$ raco pkg install sicp
ssl-connect: connect failed (error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error)
  context...:
   /usr/share/racket/collects/openssl/mzssl.rkt:1207:8: loop
   /usr/share/racket/collects/net/url.rkt:222:2: redirection-loop
   /usr/share/racket/collects/pkg/util.rkt:33:0: call/input-url+2005
   /usr/share/racket/collects/pkg/lib.rkt:226:3: for-loop
   /usr/share/racket/collects/pkg/lib.rkt:224:0: package-index-lookup
   /usr/share/racket/collects/pkg/lib.rkt:459:2: install-package228
   /usr/share/racket/collects/pkg/lib.rkt:449:0: install-packages55
   /usr/share/racket/collects/racket/file.rkt:295:8
   /usr/share/racket/collects/racket/file.rkt:284:0: call-with-file-lock24
   /usr/share/racket/collects/pkg/main.rkt: [running body]
   /usr/share/racket/collects/pkg/raco.rkt: [traversing imports]
   /usr/share/racket/collects/raco/raco.rkt: [running body]
   /usr/share/racket/collects/raco/main.rkt: [running body]
```

I don't understand, why it is happening? Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: Hang on... what version of DrRacket are you running? If it's something ancient like 5.3.1, this could explain your problem.

Comment: Yes, as @JohnClements suggests, I have only seen this error on old versions of Racket.

Comment: Thanks guys. I have installed an updated version. And problem is solved. Cheers!

Comment: And if you can't update the version the linked answer has a backup solution using the old planet code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks almost like you don't have a internet connection when you are runing this. I tried to do the same and get the following successful install:

```
sylwester:~/Apps$ raco pkg install sicp
Resolving "sicp" via https://download.racket-lang.org/releases/6.6/catalog/
Resolving "sicp" via https://pkgs.racket-lang.org
Downloading repository git://github.com/sicp-lang/sicp
raco setup: version: 6.6
raco setup: platform: x86_64-macosx [3m]
raco setup: installation name: 6.6
raco setup: variants: 3m
raco setup: main collects: /Applications/Racket v6.3/collects
raco setup: collects paths: 
raco setup:   /Users/westerp/Library/Racket/6.6/collects
raco setup:   /Applications/Racket v6.3/collects
raco setup: main pkgs: /Applications/Racket v6.3/share/pkgs
raco setup: pkgs paths: 
raco setup:   /Applications/Racket v6.3/share/pkgs
raco setup:   /Users/westerp/Library/Racket/6.6/pkgs
raco setup: links files: 
raco setup:   /Applications/Racket v6.3/share/links.rktd
raco setup:   /Users/westerp/Library/Racket/6.6/links.rktd
raco setup: main docs: /Applications/Racket v6.3/doc
raco setup: --- updating info-domain tables ---
raco setup: updating: /Users/westerp/Library/Racket/6.6/share/info-cache.rktd
raco setup: --- pre-installing collections ---
raco setup: --- installing foreign libraries ---
raco setup: --- installing shared files ---
raco setup: --- compiling collections ---
raco setup: --- parallel build using 4 jobs ---
raco setup: 3 making: <pkgs>/sicp/sicp
raco setup: 3 making: <pkgs>/sicp/sicp/lang
raco setup: 2 making: <pkgs>/sicp/sicp-pict (SICP)
raco setup: 1 making: <pkgs>/sicp/sicp-pict2
raco setup: 2 making: <pkgs>/sicp/sicp-pict/planet-docs
raco setup: --- creating launchers ---
raco setup: --- installing man pages ---
raco setup: --- building documentation ---
raco setup: 2 running: <pkgs>/sicp/sicp-pict/sicp-manual.scrbl
WARNING: collected information for key multiple times: '(exporting-libraries #f); values: '(sicp-pict) '(sicp)
WARNING: collected information for key multiple times: '(exporting-packages #f); values: '("sicp") '("sicp")
raco setup: WARNING: undefined tag in <pkgs>/sicp/sicp-pict/sicp-manual.scrbl:
raco setup:  ((lib "sicp-pict/main.rkt") amb)
raco setup:  ((lib "sicp-pict/main.rkt") black)
raco setup:  ((lib "sicp-pict/main.rkt") cons-stream)
raco setup:  ((lib "sicp-pict/main.rkt") diagonal-shading)
raco setup:  ((lib "sicp-pict/main.rkt") einstein)
raco setup:  ((lib "sicp-pict/main.rkt") gray)
raco setup:  ((lib "sicp-pict/main.rkt") paint-hires)
raco setup:  ((lib "sicp-pict/main.rkt") white)
raco setup: 3 rendering: <pkgs>/racket-index/scribblings/main/user/local-redirect.scrbl
raco setup: 2 rendering: <pkgs>/racket-index/scribblings/main/user/release.scrbl
raco setup: 1 rendering: <pkgs>/racket-index/scribblings/main/user/search.scrbl
raco setup: 0 rendering: <pkgs>/sicp/sicp-pict/sicp-manual.scrbl
raco setup: 2 rendering: <pkgs>/racket-index/scribblings/main/user/start.scrbl
WARNING: collected information for key multiple times: '(exporting-libraries #f); values: '(sicp-pict) '(sicp)
WARNING: collected information for key multiple times: '(exporting-packages #f); values: '("sicp") '("sicp")
raco setup: --- installing collections ---
raco setup: --- post-installing collections ---
```

Comment: Thanks Sylwester. Problem was actually because of older version. It solved now.